# How to filter using a function in the left side of an expression?

Tags: python, django, django-models

It is possible to execute a filter with the Django ORM using the `Replace` function on the left side? It would be to achieve something like this query:

```
select * from my_table where replace(field, '-', '') = 'value'
```

If I try to use the function at the right side, inside the filter function, I'm receiving this error: `keyword can't be an expression`

Comment: please provide the code you are trying to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Replace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#replace) database function to create an annotated field equal to your replacement that you can filter on

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Replace

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    field_replaced=Replace('field', Value('-'), Value(''))
).filter(
    field_replaced='value'
)
```